# Define strings and draw language

Tags: finite-automata, automata, automata-theory

The language of all strings defined over Σ = {A, B, C} that begins with B, ends with A and having minimum length of 3 and also draw finite automata for the language.

Please explain this in the regular expression way and language diagram. The language of all strings defined over Σ = {X, Y, Z} with Y as the third letter and Z being the second last letter

Comment: Err, is that me or does this looks surprisingly like a school assignment that you're asking the community to do for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

s -> Bx

x -> Ay | By | Cy

y -> Ay | By  | Cy | A

It is not too difficult to draw the finite automaton. The small letters are the states, the capital letters are the input symbols.

State "s" is the start state.

From there the word is started with B and ends in state "x".

From "x" the input can be A or B or C and leads to state "y".

From "y" the input can be A or B or C and the lead back to "y". The input C is particular because it can/must be the last symbol of the word. So A simply ends in a finish state (which is not explicitly mentioned in the rules).

The automaton would look like this:

[image: Finite automaton for above language]

The regular expression that recognizes the discussed language is as follows:

> `B[ABC][ABC]*A` - or shorter - `B[ABC]+A`

In this case it was simple (especially the first regular expression) to see the correspondence between the automaton and the regular expression.

---

Divyesh's answer is almost correct also, he drew a deterministic automaton. You just have to remove the transition to q4 and it's ok.

Comment: I want to make it more clear, please make language strings so it will help to understand as I am a new guy in automata theory.

Comment: Ok, give me some minutes. Will try to give good answer hopefully.

Comment: Are you acquainted with deterministic and nondeterministic automata?

Comment: @MayanKhan Check the answer. The capital letters are the strings. The small letters are the states of the automaton. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: yes it really helps me thanks!, can you please Write Regular Expressions (RE) for the this language.

Comment: @MayanKhan - check it out. Please upvote and accept the answer if you think your question was answered.

Comment: I have up voted to you thanks for your nice help can you please share with me your skype or email address so we can talk further?

Comment: Please try to find my name on a social network: Google+, Facebook, etc. My Skype is my name - so easy to find.
Please upvote the answer if you don't mind. You accepted it, thank you for that. To upvote simply click on the triangle to vote up.

Comment: very difficult to find by this way you can paste here and then delete them if you like.

Comment: Please consider upvoting the answer (the triangle that points up). Thank you for accepting it.

Comment: Please explain this in the regular expression way. The language of all strings defined over Σ = {X, Y, Z} with Y as the third letter and Z being the second last letter.

Comment: [XYZ][XYZ]Y[XYZ]*Z[XY] | [XYZ]ZY

Please upvote the comments ;-)

Comment: Please also draw Finite Automata for this language. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

automata for this must be this...[image]

Comment: I am not sure what a dead state means, but in your example you risk to infinitely accept a,b or c and never end. I think that is not correct.

Comment: I draw DFA so,i should mention all the possible outcome from the state.